# How to reorder bar plot on multiple variable-grouped bar graph based on one specific variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a bar graph with two variables plotted on the same axis. I have melted data into long format, how do I reorder the bars based on **one specific variable** which is "**Age**" in a descending order? **In long format, both "Age and Weight" variables fall under the "value" column, so it is not possible to reorder "Age" by reordering "value"**. Is there another way around this?

```
Group<-c("X1","Y1","Z1")
Age <- c(10, 15, 20)
Weight<-c(50,40,45)
df<-data.frame(Group,Age,Weight)

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df.long<-melt(df)

ggplot(df.long,aes(x=reorder(Group,-value),y=value,fill=variable))+geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.9)
```

Reordering the values of both variables does not help, it reorders based on sum of two variables:
[image]

what I really want is something similar to the graph below where the "Age" variable is in descending order, with the corresponding "Weight" variable.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the factor levels in `Group` based on `value` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df.long %>%
  arrange(variable, desc(value)) %>%
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = unique(Group))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Group,y=value,fill=variable) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.9)
```

[image]